# How to send an email at specified date which is stored in database. Nodejs

Tags: node.js, cron, mailgun

I want to send email to the user which is stored in a database. for each user, we define a specific date. when arriving this date, the system sends an email to this user automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cron-node package to do sending email work every 24 hours

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
// scheduling do a job in the node-cron
cron.schedule('0 0 0 * * *', () => {
  schedule.run_mid_night();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is being down-voted because your answer is already present in the documentation. Mention the delivery time as `o:deliverytime`.

[Example from the documentation:](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples)

```
var mailgun = require("mailgun-js");
var api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var DOMAIN = 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME';
var mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({apiKey: api_key, domain: DOMAIN});

var data = {
  from: 'Excited User <me@samples.mailgun.org>',
  to: 'bar@example.com',
  subject: 'Scheduled Message',
  text: 'Testing some Mailgun awesomeness!',
  "o:deliverytime": 'Fri, 6 Jul 2017 18:10:10 -0000'
};

mailgun.messages().send(data, function (error, body) {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Please see the documentation before posting on Stack Overflow.

The documentation can be found at: [Mailgun Documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks for response. But, The Mailgun delivery is only for 3 days in future. I use cron-node to check my database everyday and send email.